# React native popup menu can not navigate using navigation props

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-popup-menu

I have the `Message` react navigation stack screen.

```
...

class Message extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    ...
    headerRight: <MessagePopupMenu navigation={navigation} />
  });

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

And I want to use `react-native-popup-menu` to navigate to another screen.

```
...

export const MessagePopupMenu = ({ navigation }) => (
  <View>
    <Menu>
      <MenuTrigger style={styles.menuTrigger}>
        <Icon name="ios-add" size={30} color="#757575" />
      </MenuTrigger>
      <MenuOptions optionsContainerStyle={{ marginTop: 40, width: 100 }}>
        <MenuOption style={styles.menuOption}>
          <Text
            style={styles.text}
            onSelect={() => navigation.navigate("AddUser")}
          >
            AddFriend
          </Text>
        </MenuOption>
        <MenuOption>
          <Divider />
        </MenuOption>
        <MenuOption style={styles.menuOption}>
          <Text
            style={styles.text}
            onSelect={() => navigation.navigate("AddGroup")}
          >
            AddGroup
          </Text>
        </MenuOption>
      </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menuOption: {
    ...
  },
  menuTrigger: {
     ...
  },
  text: {
    ...
  }
});
```

It seems the navigation props can not pass to the `MessagePopupMenu` component, When I click the `AddFriend` and `AddGroup` menu button.

The `Message` component is already tested as a correct navigation screen.

Comment: Have you tried to console.log the props inside the MessagePopupMenu component?

Comment: There is no message report on console.log.

Comment: Do you get an error or something?
What do you get if you print do `console.log(navigation)` inside the MessagePopupMenu?

Comment: When I change my view to the debugger console, it have nothing trigger for this move.

Comment: If you dont have any errors and you cant log anything, then it is very hard to help you

Comment: shouldn't `onSelect` be on `MenuOption` instead?

Comment: @sodik, nice work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment: `onSelect` should be bound to `MenuOption` component, e.g.

```
    <MenuOption style={styles.menuOption} onSelect={() => navigation.navigate("AddGroup")}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        AddGroup
      </Text>
    </MenuOption>
```